# I try to assign an arraylike collection of elements to variables, whats wrong with my code?

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, foreach

I try to run a forEach loop on **inputs** and assign each of the elements into some variables, but something doesn't work properly.

not sure why my variables are  keep being *"not defined"*.

*js file*:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]");

inputs.forEach(function(item, index, array){

    var inputName, inputLastName, inputAge;

    if(array[index].name === "name"){
        inputName = array[index];
    }
    if(array[index].name === "lastName"){
        inputLastName = array[index];
    }
    if(array[index].name === "age"){
        inputAge = array[index];
    }
});
```

*html file:*

```
<form action="">
    <label for="name"> Name:
        <input type="text" name="name">
    </label>

    <label for="lastName"> Last Name:
        <input type="text" name="lastName">
    </label>

    <label for="age"> Age:
        <input type="text" name="age">
    </label>
</form>
```

Comment: What did you find when you stepped through your code with the debugger? What doesn't work properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your actual code is working perfectly, expect that you are making your `inputName, inputLastName, inputAge` variables local to the `foreach` loop so they won't be accessible outside it.

You need to declare them outside the loop. This is a working snippet:

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]");

var inputName, inputLastName, inputAge;

inputs.forEach(function(item, index, array) {


  if (item.name === "name") {
    inputName = array[index];
  }
  if (item.name === "lastName") {
    inputLastName = array[index];
  }
  if (item.name === "age") {
    inputAge = array[index];
  }
});

console.log(inputName);
```

```html
<label for="name">Name:
  <input type="text" name="name">
</label>

<label for="lastName">Last Name:
  <input type="text" name="lastName">
</label>

<label for="age">Age:
  <input type="text" name="age">
</label>
```

You can also use `item.name`instead of `array[index].name` to get the current iterated element.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change one small piece of your loop for it to work

the code that looks like this `array[index].name` should be updated to `item.name === "name"`

so your loop should look like this:

```
var inputName, inputLastName, inputAge;

inputs.forEach(function(item, index, array){

    if(item.name === "name"){
        inputName = array[index];
    }
    if(item.name === "lastName"){
        inputLastName = array[index];
    }
    if(item.name === "age"){
        inputAge = array[index];
    }
});
```

As noted in the comments below, while `forEach` is supported for node lists, you are going to run into cross browser issues; So while this runs fine in Chrome and Firefox, the Edge browser for example, returned this issue as I tried to run the loop `Object doesn't support property or method 'forEach'`.

Comment: Although non-standard, `.forEach` is de facto supported for `NodeList`  (which is different from `HTMLCollection`).

Comment: @georg DOM4 defines NodeList as iterable, and the WebIDL draft says that means it has `forEach`. So it's standard, but not much stabilized.

Comment: So should I say that while it's supported, it's not recommended since its not stabilized?

Comment: @comoss Well, it doesn't seem it will be removed from future specs. So the main problem is browser support.

Comment: @Oriol: ah, thanks, I looked on whatwg and there's nothing about forEach. If it's going to be spec'ed, that will be quite silly, if you ask me.

Comment: But I think `array[index].name` is exactly equivalent to `item.name` (although of course the latter is preferable). Anyway, this is completely wrong. Setting a local variable such as `inputName` will accomplish exactly nothing.

Comment: Don't put your edit history in your post. No-one cares. If they do, they can look at the edit history. Your answer should be one, single, coherent answer, not some kind of timeline of your evolving thinking.